# Winforms - Unable to load data into picture box

Tags: c#, winforms

Possible Duplicate Question

I'm unable to load image into my picture box control by using the following code.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(col_value);
picTransformerImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I get the following error.

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
```

I inserted the following content(col_value) into a table with column data type Image.

```
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
```

Comment: What type is col_value?

Comment: I will post a method that you can try as an example just replace my Base64String with yours

Comment: @MethodMan he does not keep base64 string as I understand

Comment: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020929.asp